# Connection is not associated with a managed

Tags: java-ee, postgresql, jsf-2.2, jboss, demoiselle

Um dos nossos sistemas está apresentando o erro abaixo:

```
Connection is not associated with a managed connection.org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@437f90c8
```

Esse erro tem acontecido bastante, mas não estamos conseguindo identificar o motivo.

Pesquisando no google, vi que nesse link: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1437663 provavelmente tem alguma resposta sobre o caso, porém, como é um fórum privado, não consegui ver.

Alguém ja passou por isso alguma vez?

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Connection is not associated with a managed connection.org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@437f90c8 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261) at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.proxy.QueryProxy.getResultList(QueryProxy.java:64)
```

Nós estamos utilizando o framework demoiselle 2.4.2, com Jboss AS 7.1 e postgre 9.x

Answer (score 2):

Eu peguei esse erro quando utilizei a configuração padrão para criar Pool de Conexões no JBoss.
 Após pesquisar encontrei que se tratava de como tava sendo feita a configuração de validação das conexões com o banco de dados contidas nesse Pool.
 Na documentação do [JBoss EAP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Example_Datasources.html#Example_PostgreSQL_Datasource1) tem um exemplo de configuração com o banco de dados PostgreSQL. **Possivelmente uma configuração válida para que esse erro não ocorrer seria**:

```
<datasources>
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/PostgresDS" pool-name="PostgresDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://{ip_banco}:5432/{database}</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql-{version}.jdbc4.jar</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>{user}</user-name>
      <password>{password}</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
      <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
    </validation>
  </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Apararentemente a classe definida em valid-connection-checker é a que faz o trabalho de forma correta para avaliar as conexões que estão inválidas com o banco de dados.

Att.,

Silas.